# Is there any research about secant varieties by using homotopical algebra or simplicial methods?

Tags: simplicial-stuff, projective-varieties

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra with $proj A$ is a projective variety $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$. The join $J(X,X)$ can be represented by $proj (A\otimes_kA)$ and also we can generalize it to $J(X, \cdots, X) = proj(A \otimes_k \cdots \otimes_k A)$ ($n$ times).  After taking sufficient embedding to $\mathbb{P}^n$, we can construct higher secant varieties $\sigma_k(X)$.

There is a cosimplicial object associated to ring homomorphism $R \to A$
(https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/023F)

When I found that page, I wondered if there is any applications of simplicial methods in secant varieties. However I could not find any works about my question in both arXiv and Mathoverflow.
Is there any good result about my question?